# Add comma separated values between tags

Tags: java, xml

I have one list in which I am adding data from database. My code is as follows.

```
list.add(rs.getString(rsMetaData.getColumnName()));
object.set(list);
```

Now passing this object in output file stream. I am using JAXB and DOM parser for creating XML

```
write.marshall(object,outputstream);
```

where object= this object is used to set values in xml

As per above code I am getting desired values from columns of database. After this I am setting values from list into a tag in xml. But getting all in separated tags.

My output:

```
<value>1</value>
<value>2</value>
<value>3<value>
<value>4</value>
.
.
and so on
```

Expected output:

```
<value>1,2,3,4,5</value>
```

From my code as mentioned above I am not getting in comma separated code. Please help.

Another approach I am following is using DOM parser:

```
for(String s:list){
 Element n= doc.createElement("value");
n.appendChild(doc.createTextNode((s)));
}
```

through this also I am not getting comma separated values

Comment: How do you create the XML? Can you give us the code for that?

Comment: You showed code which you have no problem with (adding data to list), but didn't show code which is causing the problem (adding data from list to XML). Use [edit] option to provide code which you have problem with.

Comment: sir I just edited my code. I think now it will be more clear

Comment: We don't know what is `object`. Please take your time and create proper [mcve] (you can limit it to minimum, we don't need part which gets data from DB, just use some predefined/fixed values instead).

Comment: sir as you can see I am doing marshalling here. Because of this I am getting my xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general approach if you want to have commaseparated values is to turn your list into a String and then add this String (not the list) to the XML. Here's one way to do that (assuming you use Java 8):

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");
String commaSeparated = String.join(",", list);
System.out.println(commaSeparated); //gives you 1,2,3,4,5
```

In your particular case (the DOM parser example you gave): In the for loop, you create one element for each value in list; what you want to do is create one entry (no for loop):

```
String commaSeparated = String.join(",", list);
Element n= doc.createElement("value");
n.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(commaSeparated));
```

Comment: sir I have added some more code at last. Please let me know incase you need any more info